# Using EF (or another .NET ORM) across multiple databases w/ identical schemas

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm

You'll have to forgive my ignorance of EF and/or ORM terminology. I'm familiar with ORMs and their purpose, but am having trouble finding if there's one that supports my use case.

I have unique databases for different clients, spreading across 3 database servers. However, the schemas of these different databases are exact. My question is, how can I go about having EF (or another .NET orm [NHibernate?]) support this type of architecture? When I generate models from a DB, it seems to create a connection string for that single database. I need it to determine the correct connection string to use at run-time.

So, save generating models for each unique client DB (which won't scale), what can I do?

Thanks for any help or direction.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to write a *general* answer because each ORM has its own rules (I made this a community wiki to merge other answers too).

### EntityFramework

Which database it'll use is declared with a connection string (usually in `app.config` file). When you create your context it'll read default one but there's a constructor that accepts it as parameter:

```
string connectionString = "...";
using (var repository= new MyRepository(connectionString))
{
}
```

Usually EF connection string defines (after its own data about model) a *standard* connection string for a provider:

```
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string= "data source=tcp:serverName;initial catalog=databaseName;user id=username;
```

Do not forget to escape `"` from code. You can read full connection string (to use it, for example as template for search & replace) from your `app.config` file. In this case you *say*: "let's use a connection with Microsoft SQL Server, this is its connection string". Just change `initial catalog` to database you want to connect to and you're done.

### DevExpress

```
string connectionString = "...";
XpoDefault.DataLayer = XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(
    connectionString,
    AutoCreateOption.DatabaseAndSchema);
```

### LightSpeed

Inherit from `ConnectionStrategy` and override `Connection` property. To use it you can set `ConnectionStrategy` property of your `ModelUnitOfWork` object.

### NHibernate

Inherit from `NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider` class and override the `GetConnection()` method. See [this example](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/18/extending-nhibernate-s-driverconnectionprovider.aspx) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Any ideas why it would be balking about using "data source" as a keyword? I'm getting a _Keyword not supported: 'data source'._

Comment: @William you should post code for your connection string. If I have to guess I'd say it's because it's not properly escaped.

Comment: You're right. I was escaping the " incorrectly! Thank a lot man.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  Thanks for the answer - I have a corollary to this question.  If I have identical schemas, but need to represent the same objects in different databases (a master client that has access to the information in child clients), is there a proper way to set up this relationship or is it better to use stateless session or .AsNoQuery() for entity framework and manage connections as part of the applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

To give some examples:

When using DevEpxress XPO ORM, you can do something like:

```
XpoDefault.DataLayer = XpoDefault.GetDataLayer("TheConnectionString, AutoCreateOption.DatabaseAndSchema);
```

When using EF code first

```
public class SiteContext : DbContext
{
    public SiteContext(): base("TheConnectionString")
    {

    }
}
```

When using LightSpeed ORM:

See link: http://www.mindscapehq.com/documentation/lightspeed/Building-Applications-with-LightSpeed/Customising-How-LightSpeed-Connects-to-the-Database

Which ORM to choose is difficult in my opinion and what I am now gonna type is rather biased:

1. DevExpress ORM XPO. Great ORM Mapper especially when used in conjunction with their product line like XAF. Their support is excellent.
2. EF code first is very simple to use. There are rumours it is rather slow compared to other ORM mappers.
3. Mindscape Lightspeed focusses on speed and design time capabilities. Excellent support.

I have been part in projects using NHibernate as an ORM mapper. The general opinion is it is highly customisable. I have worked in projects where EF failed in mapping Oracle Existing Databases where NHibernate did not. NHibernate is for a newbie not very easy to learn.

For your situation it is important you first have to check how well the ORM mapper can handle your database model.

Answer (score 0):

I've just extended our system to support multi-tenants, in which each tenant is backed by a separated database. Our system uses NHibernate.

My solution is simple: just inherit `NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider` class, override the `GetConnection()` method to returns the correct connection. With this you can use one SessionFactory object to manage multiple databases which have the same schema.

Of course the implementation was much more complex, but it involved adapt the entire system from single tenant to multi tenants.